# How to check Mapreduce jobs logs in Hortonworks sandbox with HDP 2.4

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

Might be a lame question but even after a lot of research i still couldn't figure out how to check map reduce job logs from resource manager UI in hortonworks sandbox.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ragzz

There are two mechanisms to check logs.

1. From Ambari UI, navigate to MapReduce2 and then find the QuickLinks on the top of the screen. Navigate to JobHistory Logs
2. Alternatively, navigate to /var/log/hadoop-mapreduce/mapred directory where all the mapreduce job related logs can be found out.

Let me know how it goes. Many Thanks

[image]